# ¿Cómo hacer para que una variable booleana cambie de valor en otro arcivo en python?

Tags: python, booleano

Tengo dos archivos en Python (a.py y j.py). En j.py hice una función en el que cambia una variable booleana y en a.py solamente imprime la función de j.py. Ya hice el programa y todo pero cuando imprimo la función en a.py la variable booleana no se modifica, es como que no haya pasado por la función que hice para cambiarla.

```
# Este es j.py
bat = False

def length():
    global bat
    if len('bat') == 3:
        bat = True
    return 'bat is'introducir el código aquí
```

```
# Este es a.py

from j import  length, bat

print(length(), bat)
```

Al final, solamente quiero que imprima (en a.py) “bat is True”, pero imprime “bat is False”.
Si alguien sabe como hacer que la variable booleana cambie, sería de mucha ayuda (necesito que cambie de valor dentro de una función pero si no es posible entenderé).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido Daniel c:

## Explicación

Esta linea `from j import  length, bat`, es equivalente al siguiente código:

```
import j
length = j.length
bat = j.bat
del j
```

Esto significa que realmente el valor si cambia, solo que no obtienes el nuevo valor.

Teniendo en cuenta la equivalencia, tu código se vería así:

```
# Este es a.py

import j
length = j.length
bat = j.bat
del j

print(length(), bat)
```

Como podrás ver, el booleano se obtiene una sola vez y se guarda en la variable bat. No importa el valor de j.bat, bat siempre tendrá de valor False, ya que eso valía cuando importaste a j.py.

Espero haberme explicado bien, cualquier cosa que no entiendas de la explicación dime.

## Solucion

Para solucionar esto, se puede directamente importar a j.py (sin el from) y preguntarle el valor de bat cuando haces el print.

```
# Este es a.py
import j

# al hacer j.bat obtengo el valor actual de bat en j.
print(j.length(), j.bat)
```